# Multiple OR options in Jekyll include (liquid template)

Tags: html, include, jekyll, liquid

I have created an `image` include a lot like the one in the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/).

I am setting the `alt` tag based on the `alt` variable if provided, otherwise setting a default one to try and shame myself into providing one:

`alt="{{ include.alt | default: "Whoops! alt tag not provided. Please let me know via the contact page"}}"`

I also have an optional caption which might be a reasonable alternative (excuse the pun) to the `alt` tag (if `caption` is set but `alt` isn't).

I tried `{{ include.alt | include.caption | default: "Whoops! alt tag not ..."}}` but when `alt` is blank and caption is set it still uses the default value.

Is there an elegant way to do this or do I need to use multiple if/unless blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I misunderstood what was happening. I was reading the vertical bars as ORs (ruby style) rather than as pipes (unix style). In Liquid the pipes are used as [filters](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters).

The solution was to use the default filter twice:

`{{ include.alt | default: include.caption | default: "Whoops! alt tag not ..." }}`